# How should I jumper the transformer to use a thermostat with my heat pump?

Tags: wiring, hvac

I am hooking up an aftermarket blower motor on my Trane XL 1400 AC/heat pump. I have a black, blue, red & white wires coming out of the new motor. I am bypassing the circuit board so I am connecting black & white wires to to outside of the contactor, and capping off the red, which is low speed anyways.

How do I hook a jumper up from the transformer so I will be able to use my thermostat?

Comment: Why are you bypassing the control board instead of replacing it?

Comment: Why not just add a relay to control the operation of the motor and use the thermostat to control the A/C unit the way we did it in the cave man days

Comment: Cant afford new control board.

Comment: Ive been without air for 5 days now im desperate i just want to power the motor on high thats the quickest and cheapest way to get air .

Comment: If you can't afford the board how can you afford to run the A/C? By the time you are done you may need more than the board. You could hot wire the motor and get the power from another source.

Comment: I think you are going to need a contactor 24v coil to pull in and use 240 from the supply conductors. Most of the variable speed motors are running from 3 phase that is developed from 240 single phase. By using a contactor or relay capable of switching motor loads at the new motors listed value it can be done.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that I should a variable speed unit. The old motor should have had a whole mess of white wires connected to the control board along with a couple colored wires. I have never tried to retrofit one with a PSC motor, other parts of the system probably won’t work. At any rate you would at least need a relay since the blower is 240 volt and the thermostat is 24 volt. If this were a standard PSC motor originally just hook the common to one leg of the contractor and run the speed tap through the relay. Hook the common wire to one side of the coil and the fan wire to the other side of the coil.

Comment: You might want to re-read and revise your first sentence. I'm not sure what it's meant to say or I'd take care of it for you.